# What is the difference between version v2.0.50727.3053 and v2.0.50727.3074 of the .Net framework?

Tags: .net

I have a file from source control that has been auto-generated by another person. As such, it has a comment at the top along the lines of:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3074
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The version in source control has the version 2.0.50727.3074 stamped in it. When I re-generate this file on my local development machine, it stamps it with version 2.0.50727.3053.

Searching on Google for these version number has turned up lots of hits, but none of them tell me what the difference is between these two runtime versions.

I'm assuming that I am missing some kind of update/hotfix/service pack, but what? I have VS2008 (9.0.30729.1) SP1 installed with .Net 3.5 SP1.

---

**EDIT**: for completeness, here is what I've found from the links below:

.3053 is .Net 2.0 SP2 (that also ships with .Net 3.5 SP1)

.3074 and .3082 are both KB958481 (Application Compatibility Update for the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2). The difference between them is that .3074 is for Vista and Win2008, whereas .3082 is for WinXP and Win2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this [information.](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/07/12/438245.aspx)
 2.0.50727.3053 was released with .NET 3.5 SP1
  2.0.50727.3074 was an update i.e. KB 958481 released after .NET 3.5 SP1.

> Monday, June 29, 2009 1:11 PM by
>   karelz
>
> ## re: What .NET Framework version numbers go with what service pack
>
> 2.0.50727.3074 is the WinXP/Win2003 version of the same hotfix (KB
>   958481).
>
> 2.0.50727.3082 is the Vista/Win2008 version.

Answer (score 9):

3053 is .NET Framework 2.0 **SP1**,
3074 is .NET Framework 2.0 **SP2**:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/pages/asp-net-2-0-fixes.aspx

Comment: I think 3053 is mentioned to be part of .NET 2 SP2 shipped with .NET 3.5 SP1